# How to extract field based on field value

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

```
%Input structure
s.a=[1; 2; 1; 3; 4; 1; 2]
s.b=[4; 9; 7; 1; 0; 3; 8]
% output required
s.a=[1; 1; 1]
s.b=[4; 7; 3]
```

The actual structure contains many fields of long size. How to extract corresponding field values, when condition is put for field 'a' (when a==1).

Comment: please can you explain better what elements you want extract?

Comment: these are based on condition i.e. values in field 'a'. When value in field 'a' equals 1, then its corresponding values from other fields be extracted

Answer (score 3):

Try this and adapt to the other fields:

```
s.b(s.a==1)
```

To do it for all fields in *s* except *a* and collect the results in a struct *t* you can use a loop:

```
t = struct()
fn = fieldnames(s);
for k=1:numel(fn)
    t.(fn{k}) = s.(fn{k})(s.a==1);
end
```

Comment: Is it generalizable to large no. of fields?

Comment: As I understand your structure *s* has many fields (like s.c and s.d and so on). You can write one statement for each field but it can also be done by looping over the fields.

Comment: OP wants to do this to `s.a` as well. Why not `I = s.a==1`, then go into your loop but without the condition?

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Made a change.